# How to change arrow direction when click in Select option

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

> I want the arrow to move up when I open the select dropdown option.

```html
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think the most you can do is make your dropdown AFAIK

Comment: ok let me try it

Comment: not it is not working

Comment: "make your dropdown" i mean create your own dropdown using javascript and HTML from the start. You don't have to do it though, that's all I know about making that happen

Comment: I know i was looking for short cut man

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try this one out,

```css
select{
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chevron-down" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/></svg>') no-repeat right #ddd;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
    background-position: right 0.1rem center;
}
select:focus {
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chevron-up" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 5.707l-5.646 5.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l6-6z"/></svg>') no-repeat right #ddd;
    background-position: right 0.1rem center;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

The icons are from bootstrap, [Chevron up](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/chevron-up/) and [Chevron down](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/chevron-down/)

Comment: Select an option from the dropdown, the arrow will be pointing up itself, because its still in the focus state,

Comment: can you please make small one it has large width which I don't want can please adjust width according to text width only

Comment: @shawaizminhas see the update

Comment: This doesn't work if I try to `blur` or `unfocus` it by clicking on the dropdown again

Comment: @Nitheesh and Robo yeah, they are here. js for the rescue